# How to make directive execution deterministic in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an interesting situation here that I have not ran into in the past and I am not sure if there is an "Angular" way of doing this natively.  Basically, I started out with a simple button like this:

```
<button type="btn" ng-disabled="model.isDisabled">My Button</button>
```

As you can see there's nothing special here except for the ngDisabled directive I am using.  I recently developed an Authorization infrastructure made up of an Angular service, a directive, and a utility service. Essentially it checks the permissions of the given user and references them with a set of required permissions in order to see if a given element should be disabled or not.  Applying this Authorization directive to my button yields the following:

```
<button type="btn" sk-auth sk-auth-enable="[AuthPermissions.Restore]" ng-disabled="model.isDisabled">My Button</button>
```

Here you will see I am simply passing in an array of permissions that the user needs in order for this button to be enabled. So if this user has the "Restore" permission, then this button should be enabled.  The issue here is that my directive and the ngDisabled directive conflict.  My directive runs and will disable the element, but then the next digest cycle will run and the ngDisabled directive will re-enable it because the expression in "ng-disabled" is falsy.

Essentially, I need my directive to be ran first and if it determines the user CAN use this button, then it allows the other ngDisabled directive to work normally, but if it can't use the button, then the skAuth directive will disable it permanently.

Is there a fundamental flaw in my architecture? Do I need to completely re-write this Authorization infrastructure in order to accommodate this scenario?  I originally thought of just using a method that gets called inside the ng-disabled, like `ng-disabled="!hasAuthAccess(AuthPermissions.Restore)"`, but that causes this method to be called on each digest cycle which isn't needed and we would have to start mixing Authorization logic with business logic and I would rather keep them seperated.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Data binding presumes that data may change. Since you have your own directive, it can do everything that `ng-disabled` does and replace it.

Comment: I was sort of thinking this... so if I get you correctly, just take the expression in `ng-disabled` and put it into my directive like `sk-auth-disabled="{ expression}"` and then just add the ngDisabled directive directly in the link function using the expression?

Comment: All that ng-disabled does is adding/removing `disabled` attribute. You just don't need it when you have your own directive.

Comment: Ok I think I got it... so now my directive takes another attribute `sk-auth-disabled="{expression}"` and if the button is enabled via the Authorization logic, then it reverts to using the "expression" statement to determine the "disabled" property value

Comment: Yep, that's the way I would do that.

Comment: Ok thanks, that did work and was probably the simplest change from what I had before. Would have been nice to be able to continue using ng-disabled, but i don't think there is an easy way

Comment: Built-in directives are there to spare some time and don't encumber controllers with DOM operations. This makes no sense if you already have a directive, a simple built-in directive like ng-disabled or ng-click would just create overhead (moreover, you don't need to bind a value).